# linked-server sql - access Problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, linked-server

I have a SQL server 2000 and an Access database mdb connected by Linked server on the other hand I have a program in c # that updates data in a SQL table (Users) based data base access.

When running my program returns the following error message:

`OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' reported an error. Authentication failed.
[OLE / DB provider returned message: Can not start the application. Missing information file of the working group or is opened exclusively by another user.] OLE DB error trace [OLE / DB Provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' IDBInitialize:: Initialize returned 0x80040E4D: Authentication failed.]´ .`

Both the program, the sql server and database access are on a remote server.

On the local server the problem was solved by running the following:

`"sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'ActSC', 'false', NULL, 'admin', NULL".`

Try on the remote server the next, without result: 
`"sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'ActSC', true, null, 'user', 'pass'".`

On the remote server and from the "Query Analyzer" sql update statements are working correctly.

Can you think of what may be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't access mdw file remotely? Specify remote mdw file location in provider string (Jet OLEDB:System Database=MySystem.mdw) and allow access to it from local server.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is related to user impersonation. Simply said: when you use Query Analyser you're using a different login than when you're accessing the server from your C# application. Try by setting the same username & password in your C# app.

You could solve this by configuring the linked server connection with a username and password, so that SQL server disregards any other password/current user credentials. Just use/check the last option/radio in this printscreen (disregard the login mappings list in the middle) and enter the username & password to use for ALL connections:

[image: Linked Server Properties]
<sub>(source: [msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/jorgepc/WindowsLiveWriter/LessonsLearntwhileConfiguringSecurityonL_D8C9/19102009B_thumb.png))</sub>